# Is it still an open question to select the parameter of Gaussian kernel SVMs?

Tags: machine-learning, svm

I am learning Gaussian kernel SVMs recently. I have to choose the parameter $\epsilon$ for Gaussian kernel,
$$k(x,t)=e^{-\frac{\|x-y\|_2^2}{2\epsilon}}.$$

I try to find the answer in literature. I found some to analyze the parameters like '[A User's Guide to Support Vector Machines](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/20221922)' ([PDF](http://pyml.sourceforge.net/doc/howto.pdf)). I really want to analyze these by myself step by step. But I have work to finish, you know. I found a paper '[Practical Selection of SVM Parameters and Noise Estimation for SVM Regression](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/14690712)' ([PDF](http://www.svms.org/parameters/CherkasskyMa2004.pdf)).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There isn't really any method that is superior to optimizing a cross-validation based estimate of some appropriate performance statistic.  Bounds on the leave-one-out cross-validation error (such as the [radius-margin](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpls/abs_all.jsp?arnumber=1031955&tag=1) bound or the [span bound](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1023/A:1012450327387)) are computationally efficient, but are no more theoretically attractive than conventional cross-validation.  This optimisation can be performed via simple [grid search](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1961199) methods, or via standard optimisation methods, such as [gradient descent](http://eprints.pascal-network.org/archive/00002626/) or [Nelder-Mead simplex](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpls/abs_all.jsp?arnumber=1716307) method (which I use quite a lot).  However, if there are many kernel parameters to be optimised, it is often rather easy to [over-fit the model selection criterion](http://jmlr.org/papers/volume11/cawley10a/cawley10a.pdf) and end up with a model that performs rather badly.  In that case, I would recommend [regularising the model selection criterion](http://jmlr.org/papers/volume8/cawley07a/cawley07a.pdf).

Note that while the VC dimension of an SVM is bounded by the radius-margin bound, this is no longer valid if you optimise the kernel to maximise the radius-margin ratio.  As a result, tuning the kernel to maximise the radius-margin bound does not itself fall within the VC framework.

There is a great need for more theoretical analysis of model selection for kernel machines, however I suspect progress will be relatively slow in this area as the kernel parameters are much less mathematically tractable than analysis of the kernel machine itself (which can be viewed as a linear model in a fixed, kernel-induced, feature space).